# How to pass the gps location value to other class in android?

Tags: android, gps

i using a class to get the lat and lon value, after checking i confirm the data was correct, but i facing the problem which is how to passing the value to other function and send it to php script so i can store the value. Both function is under same class. Below is my get location class code.

From here i get the gps value.

```
public void get_location(){

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) LoginActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            String lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            String lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

}
```

I need to pass the value to this function so it can send to server.

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost.com/save.php"); 

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("lat", lat);
            postDataParams.put("lon", lon);
            Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Here is the function i execute asyn task

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new SendPostRequest().execute();

}
```

Comment: Do u want to pass the lat,lng to next activity or need to pass to `Asynctask`

Comment: Hi, is pass lat,lng to Asyntask

Comment: where are you executing the `Asynctask`? is it inside getlocation() ?

Comment: I updated the code, please check, thank you for reply

Comment: Man where is your `get_location` method , please add full code if possible!

Comment: You can use Interface concept to pass data from one class to other. Once you got the lat long pass that via interface reference to your activity and then from that method you can invoke asyncTask to send it to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global `Double` array (very basic) :

```
static Double[] arr;
```

In your `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new SendPostRequest().execute(arr); //changes made here
}
```

Your `get_location` method:

```
public void get_location(){

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) LoginActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            // getting location of user, don't parse to string latlng has to double
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lon = location.getLongitude();
            arr[0] = lat; //changes made here
            arr[1] = lon; //changes made here

        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

}
```

Pass value to `Asynctask` :

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(Double arr) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost.com/save.php"); 

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("lat", arr[0]); //changes made here
            postDataParams.put("lon", arr[1]); //changes made here
            Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this part of your code:

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, String> {

protected void onPreExecute(){}

protected String doInBackground(Double... arg0) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost.com/save.php"); 

        JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
        postDataParams.put("lat", args[0]);
        postDataParams.put("lon", args[1]);
```

And execute AsyncTask:

```
 new SendPostRequest().execute(lat,lon);
```